# Determine AWS Region from IP Address?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to determine the AWS Region that my heroku database is stored on.  All I have is the IP address.

How can i determine the AWS region?

Comment: If it has a public IP, you can look at this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the JSON file AWS IP ranges: [AWS IP Address Ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

It contains the `CIDR`s. You may want to write a simple script and check if the IP falls in any of the `CIDR`s and then retrieve the corresponding region. This is how JSON looks:

```
{
  "ip_prefix": "13.56.0.0/16",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "service": "AMAZON"
},
```

Here is `Python3` code to find the region, given an IP. Assumes the `ip-ranges.json` file downloaded from AWS is in the current directory. Will not work in `Python 2.7`

```
from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address
import json

def find_aws_region(ip):
  ip_json = json.load(open('ip-ranges.json'))
  prefixes = ip_json['prefixes']
  my_ip = ip_address(ip)
  region = 'Unknown'
  for prefix in prefixes:
    if my_ip in ip_network(prefix['ip_prefix']):
      region = prefix['region']
      break
  return region
```

**Test**

```
>>> find_aws_region('54.153.41.72')
'us-west-1'
>>> find_aws_region('54.250.58.207')
'ap-northeast-1'
>>> find_aws_region('154.250.58.207')
'Unknown'
```

Comment: FWIW, if you get `ipaddress.AddressValueError:...Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?`, then wrap the string argument in `unicode()`